# React render function doesn't render the returned components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I execute `npm start`, it opens localhost:3000 but doesn't display anything, just a white page. Then, I tried to insert a paragraph inside `<body>` in index.html, and when the page showed up, the text `Hello World!` only showed for less than 1 second, then disappeared. Any solution would be much appreciated

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br/>
        <Route path="/" component={ExercisesList} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
        <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
        <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the browser console and you'll see the error.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have to wrap those <Route> tags in a <Routes> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code is the `<Route>` tags are not wrapped inside `<Routes>` tag. This code solves it.

```
import React from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" component={ExercisesList} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
          <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```